# Where to upload my p12 to GCM console

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

I have already setup my iOS app to receive push notification via GCM before. I have uploaded my p12 before. Now, my iOS apps are not working anymore. They dont receive the push notification and the error says "Internal Server Error". So I decided to create a new certificate and want to upload the new p12 file. BUT I CANNOT FIND THE PAGE WHERE TO UPLOAD THE FILE. It was so easy locate before. Now it keep on showing the FIREBASE console which I do not care. I want to use the old one. Btw, my production environment is still working. What Im trying to setup now is for my sandbox env. Can someone help me find that page?

Comment: Maybe you need this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client , Check ->Upload your APNs certificate

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me. Im like fighting Google. No choice. Really need to use Firebase now. It will auto import your old projects from the old console. Just need to find correct tab and upload the APNS cert there.